# How to specify the object type so it is recognized prior to running the code in Python?

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following code excerpt:

```
import pickle
with open('my_object.pkl','r') as f:
  object = pickle.load(f)
```

**My question is:**

Suppose `object` is from a class I defined previously, how can I specify this in the code such that my interpreter knows *prior* to running the code what the object class is ? My goal here is to have the auto-completion of my IDE (I use VSCode) recognize the object so I can auto-complete and easily search the methods and attributes of that object.

Comment: In later versions of Python you can use type hints: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: How would you know anything about an object prior to reading the file?

Comment: I created that file say, and I know what the object is. I want my interpreter to know what object type is expected. Logically if the type is incorrect, it should trigger an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the version of Python and IDE, but in general looks like an additional statement with assertion instance type is the only way so far. This will trigger VS autocomplete settings

```
import pickle
with open('my_object.pkl','r') as f:
    object = pickle.load(f)
    assert isinstance(object, YourType)
    # and now you can use autocompletion with the object
```

The following issue is tracking that feature: [#82](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/82).